# Rally Connector (Yeti) and checking for changes

Tags: ruby, yeti, rally

Does the Rally Connector (Yeti) use polling of web services, or some sort of event driven functionality to check for changes?

Comment: Do you mean "polling", rather than "poling"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Yeti connector polls to determine if new changes have been made. At this time Rally does not have any method of pushing events on artifact changes other than by doing something clever with email notifications.